# How to force encodind for specific file type in Atom editor?

Tags: atom-editor

I would like to force WESTERN encoding (ISO 8859-1) for a specific filetype. I made a language package for grammar and snipperts and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing [editor-settings](https://atom.io/packages/editor-settings) package